# Calling function with const void * parameter in C

Tags: c, pointers, constants, void

Compiler reports error:

"argument of type "uint8_t" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *" (see code below)

Declarations of the two functions are:

```
// param[in]  addr   - First Radio register address
// param[out] buffer - Buffer where to copy the registers data
// param[in]  size   - Number of registers to be read
void SX1276ReadBuffer( uint8_t addr, uint8_t *buffer, uint8_t size );
```

and

```
// param[in]  handle   - Pointer to a SPI driver handle
// param[in]  txBuffer - Transmit data buffer
// param[out] rxBuffer - Receive data buffer
// param[in]  count    - Number of bytes in transfer
Ecode_t SPIDRV_MTransferB( SPIDRV_Handle_t handle, const void *txBuffer, void *rxBuffer, int count )
```

The first function is platform independent, while the second one is not. The definition of the first function (which is called by the higher layers of the chip driver, written by manufacturer) is:

```
void SX1276ReadBuffer( uint8_t addr, uint8_t *buffer, uint8_t size )
{
    uint8_t i;
    uint8_t *rxBuffer;
    uint8_t startAddr = addr & 0x7F;

    SPIDRV_MTransferB(handle, &startAddr, rxBuffer, 1);

    for( i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        SPIDRV_MTransferB(handle, 0, buffer[i], 1);  ////// THIS LINE REPORTS ERROR
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: where is `handle` defined for ReadBuffer?

Comment: Handle is already obtained in void main(). In the file hal.h (where the function is declared), handle is declared as extern SPIDRV_Handle_t handle; I'm not sure how to call function when it has generic pointers, when I have e.g. uint8_t data type. For sure, there has to be some explicit data type conversion, but I'm not sure how to do that. When I use function SPIDRV_MTransmitB with following parameters: SPIDRV_MTransmitB( handle, buffer, 2 ); (memset(buffer,0x50,2);) it works perfectly because I can see it on the scope that uC transmits exactly two bytes 0x50.

Answer (score 0):

`txBuffer` and `rxBuffer` must be valid addresses of memory chunks. So your call is probably false for two reasons :

1. It is highly not probable that the address of a `uint8_t` could be
   used as a good transmit buffer.
2. For `rxBuffer` the problem is that it does not point to any memory
   (the pointer is not initialized).

So you must define where the data will be read/write from/to. I did not know how the function `SPIDRV_MTransferB` really work. `count` is not clearly specified, which length it refers to ?

Your call should probably look like :

```
txBuffer = malloc(some_size); // or derive an address from addr param ?
rxBuffer = malloc(some_size); // or ?
SPIDRV_MTransferB(handle, &startAddr, rxBuffer, some_size);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
here is the function prototype:

Ecode_t SPIDRV_MTransferB( 
                         SPIDRV_Handle_t handle, 
                         const void *txBuffer,
                         void *rxBuffer, 
                         int count )

here is the call to that function:

SPIDRV_MTransferB(
                         handle,    // code not posted to verify this parameter
                         0,         // this, at best, defines a pointer to addr 0
                         buffer[i], // this is the contents of buffer[i], not a pointer
                         1);        // this parameter is ok.

suggest:

SPIDRV_MTransferB(handle, NULL, &(buffer[i]), 1);

to be of any further assistance, we need a description 
of exactly what the SPIDRV_MTransferB()
is expected to perform when any pointer passed to it is NULL.
```